# Can I call a mysql SP from a select like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, call

Mysql problem , When I replace the select of friends_of stored procedure with that call it works but calling the SP results in

> Error 1064

```
SELECT * 
FROM people
WHERE people.id IN (CALL friends_of(123))
```

Any comments ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Procedure within a Select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500091/mysql-procedure-within-a-select)

Comment: checked that link @1000111 , you mean I should call that SP and then later use the variable name generated inside that SP ?

Comment: What is the content of `friends_of`? maybe can be done using a little mod

Comment: for example something like : 
233,4345,2323,5453,2323,64534,23234,5534

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure can't be called from the select query.

```
   call procedurename(argumentlist);
```

Comment: thanks , but can you apply it in my example ?
that would be a shame if I cant call them from a select ...

Comment: You may please create the function instead of procedure then you can call it from your select query